# Is there any difference between 'often' and 'frequently'?

Tags: differences, synonyms, adverbs

Do both mean exactly the same or do they have slightly different meanings?

Answer (score 12):

Personally I would put more of a regular scheme to frequently, as the word comes from the same stem as frequency (a sine curve of certain wave length, therefore repeating itself in a certain pattern). Often would denote more of an irregularity.

Maybe this is a déformation professionel, as I am programmer with a math background, or I derive it from German and Latin languages, for example French:

fréquenter quelquechose would mean to regularly go somewhere.

Therefore I would hear this

1. I frequently go to the gym - usually I go there several times a week on the same days each week
2. I often go to the gym - I go there as often as I can, but can't keep a clear schedule

Comment: The same expression exists in English -- "to frequent s.th", meaning "visit on a regular basis". Even without relevance to regularity, I'd still grade them in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, although the meaning is essentially the same, to the point of one being used as a definition for the other in some dictionaries, *often* is an order of magnitude more common than *frequently.* Secondly, they occur together (collocate) with [different words](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=14302318).

I can't see a clear semantic pattern to the collocations, but it does seem that the strongest collocations for *frequently* also commonly co-occur with *often,* but the strongest collocates for *often* usually don't go with *frequently.* This suggests that *often* has a broader meaning that includes *frequently* but goes beyond it.

Answer (score 1):

In colloquial English, they mean the same thing. Remember the pun in *The Pirates of Penzance* (which only works in British English): *"When you say 'often', do you mean 'often' 'someone who has lost his parents' or 'often' 'frequently'?"*

If there is a difference, it is that "frequently" describes a periodic relationship with an ongoing action, while "often" means a lot of times during the defined period. In effect, it's the same thing, just a very slightly different flavor.

Answer (score 0):

They have the same meaning:

http://thesaurus.com/browse/frequently

Answer (score 0):

Same meaning but 'frequent', is something happens again and again while 'often', is more of an action you do again and again.

Ex: I get loose motion frequently. Therefore, I often go to toilet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example using *frequently*:

> I have dentist appointments ***frequently***.

And here is an example using *often*:

> I go to the bathroom ***often***.

Comment: It's an example but doesn't really _explain_ the difference.

Comment: I bet your dentist hates that!

Comment: "I have dentist appointments frequently, during which I often go to the bathroom in his sink"